# VS Code BrokenImport error doesn't disappear golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have this irritating error message that doesn't go away even though go runs the script successfully. I have already updated go tools. I checked out directories that are specified in this error message and actually it turns out that there are no package files here for downloaded modules, but they downloaded under $GOPATH/pkg directory. What should I do in order to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open from a directory with go.mod file (module root) or a subdirectory of the main module. If you cannot (e.g. because you have to work with multiple modules), you will need to opt in to use the experimental mode with "gopls": { "build.experimentalWorkspaceModule": true } setting. This is a known limitation of the Go language server currently.
Answer by [Hana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5037198/hana)

Answer (score 0):

By default all our packages are downloaded into `$GOPATH/pkg` directory.

The issue that you are facing is happened due to `sync` issue in VSCode. Sometimes VSCode takes few second for sync meanwhile it will show an error.

You can get rid of with this issue by restarting the VSCode but make sure you have followed official docs Golang for VSCode.

1. Make sure your tools are up to date: run `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`,
   type Go and chose `Install/Update tools`.
2. Try moving your project out of the GOPATH, and setting up `go.mod` for
   it.
3. Restart the VSCode editor

Make sure after `go get package_name` you should press `ctrl`+`s` though if you have turned on autosave. After 1 or 2 second popup will occur down right side saying changes are being saved and error will move away.

This is why when you opened code in new window error is gone.

Comment: restarting vs code is the first thing that came up when I tried to fix this problem, and obviously I wouldn't have asked if it was that simple to fix

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `go.mod` file is in the workspace root. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49715